# Using Cookies to check if someone has visited a page

Tags: php, mysql, cookies

When a user visits one page I have:

```
setcookie("firstvisit", time()+3600);
```

In a functions file which is included in the header of every page I have:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['firstvisit'])) {
$run = mysql_query("UPDATE `table` SET `firstvisit` = 1 WHERE `id` = '".$_SESSION['uid']."'");
setcookie("firstvisit", time()-3600);
```

If I do it like this (and it works) it means the script will run every time the user clicks on that page. Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will only set *firstvisit* to 1 in the database on the second visit. This is because `isset($_COOKIE['firstvisit'])` must evaluate to true for the query to run, and cookies are only available in the next request - `setcookie()` doesn't add to the `$_COOKIE` array.

```
// assumes $_SESSION['uid'] is always set

if(!isset($_COOKIE['firstvisit'])) {
    setcookie('firstvisit', time()); //set a cookie containing the timestamp of when this user first visited the page
    $run = mysql_query("UPDATE `table` SET `firstvisit` = 1 WHERE `id` = '".$_SESSION['uid']."'");
}
else {
    //it's not their first visit because the cookie already exists
}
```

Be aware that this logic won't work on multiple pages - the cookies will overwrite each other and the code will become unreliable.

Comment: assuming I understand this (new to php, trying to learn sessions and cookies now), I would include this function in the header of the page I want to use. and it will automatically set the firstvisit row to 1. so question: why don't i need to include a time for setcookie? does leaving it blank automatically set it as the timestamp for shen they first visited?and two, do i not need to close the cookie or is it fine left how it is?

Comment: Cookies aren't foolproof; they stay with a single device and can be cleared at any time. 1: you are including the current time as the second argument. 2: if you did close the cookie, it would be set again next request and the database updated (to the same value) - which would be pointless :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if the cookie is previously set or not before setting it.

```
if( !isset($_COOKIE['firstvisit']) ){ //if the cookie is not set
  //set your cookie 
} //skip otherwise
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to update the value every time. check that value in database whether it's already exist or not?